# How to open Firefox URL having GET parameter, through Linux Command line

Tags: command-line, firefox

Not sure if it was asked before but I really couldnt find anything related to this. Heres my Question. Opening a URL in firefox through linux command line works fine, like below:

```
firefox www.google.com
```

But, how do I open a URL having GET params, e. g.:

```
firefox www.google.com?param1=val1
```

It URL Encodes the whole URL and converts the `?` to `%3F`. 
On window open, the URL becomes: `www.google.com%3Fparam1=val1` and not understood by the browser.

Comment: I don't use firefox. But I think this shoud work `firefox "www.google.com?param1=val1"`

Answer (score 7):

If you type that from a command prompt then the shell will parse the `?`
(The same will happen if your URL contains an ampersand (`&`) or an asterix (`*`).

To avoid this use double quotes around the part you do not want the shell to parse.

E.g. 
`/usr/local/bin/firefox "http://www.google.com?param1=val1"`

Answer (score 1):

Please check the result of `` file `which firefox` ``,and check if it is a script file, not a executable file. If it's a script file, then it would be very likely that it doesn't quote the arguments correctly.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem. The answer for us was to fully-qualify the url, including the `http://` part.

For example, this works:

```
firefox http://www.google.ch?q=fred
```